# Benefits of Angular libraries vs Angular modules in a monorepo? NX architecture

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I'm wondering what are the benefits of working with libraries rather than modules in Angular, as nx.dev recommends for an monorepo architecture.

I understand the benefits for a npm publishable feature like interfaces that another repo will consume, but why would I want to make a library out of a business related feature, like a homepage, for example :

```
myorg/
├── apps/
│   ├── todos/
│   └── todos-e2e/
├── libs/
      ├── todos/
        ├── home/   <-- why nx recommends making a library here?
          ├── src/
            ├── lib/
              ├── home.component.html/ts/scss
              ├── home.module.ts
├── tools/
├── README.md
├── workspace.json
├── nx.json
├── package.json
```

rather than

```
myorg/
├── apps/
│   ├── todos/
         [...]
         ├── home/   <-- just a simple lazy loaded module here
           ├── home.component.html/ts/scss
           ├── home.module.ts
│   └── todos-e2e/
├── libs/
├── tools/
├── README.md
├── workspace.json
├── nx.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NX recommends that you put more **than 90%** of your code in libs and the **the purpose of those libs is not only sharing code between the different applications** we can create an lib even if the code is not shared  and use app folders only for configurations like **routings** and environments.

we have to mention the benefits of separating your code into small units (libs) that you can **test and build them individually**.

so in your case it can be a lib that can be lazy loaded into your app it can manage it's own routes, here is the list of libs types taken from their book

- Feature libraries: Developers should consider feature libraries as libraries that implement smart UI (with injected services) for specific business use cases or pages in an application.
- UI libraries: A UI library contains only presentational components.
- Data-access libraries: A data-access library contains services and utilities for interacting with a back-end system. It also includes all the code related to State management.
- Utility libraries: A utility library contains common utilities and services used by many libraries and applications.

when you see all those types of libs you understand that the idea is to have the max of code in libs insteand of apps.

i invite you to check this when **Victor Savkin** talked about libs

https://youtu.be/qYNiOKDno_I?t=6m35s

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that Victor and the Nwrl team recommands using 99% of code into libraries. But why? Is it about consistency purpose?

Comment: What are the benefits?

Comment: there is also the benefits of separating your  code into small units (libs) that you can test and build individually.

Comment: @FatehMohamed, I don't understand your answer.  Look at the example of the home component is can be the same in the lib or in a distinct folder in the app. It doesn't mean that the component in the lib would be smaller.

Comment: Looks like contradiction between angular libs and nrwl libs. I really don't understand their point :/ For example i don't understand why i should store entire app with routing inside libs folder. What's the purpose and benefits? Kinda weird